# Passing a void function as an argument to another function

Tags: c++, function, void, openframeworks

I'm trying to pass a void function to another void function, unsuccessfully so far. So I created this function inside the class called ExitButton like this. ExitButton.h:

```
class ExitButton{

 void setup(void (*_setup));

};
```

Then I include that class into another class like this. ofApp.h:

```
include "ExitButton.h"
class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{

 void update();
 void setup(); 
 StartButton *startButton;

}
```

So in my ofApp.cpp I want to call the update function like this:

```
void ofApp::update(){


exitButton->setup(setup()); // This throws me the following error: Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (*)' with an rvalue of type void
    }
```

So I assume, I can only pass a void function that is a pointer?
Is it actually possible to pass a void function as a parameter to another function?

Comment: Why do you have a `()` after `setup`? You are trying to pass the function, right? But `()` is used to *call* a function.

Comment: Seems you don't want to call `setup` there, but pass it. Also, a member-function is a completely different animal from a normal function.

Comment: @DavidSchWartz even if I do it with out the (), it throws me the same error

Comment: @Deduplicator so it isn't possible?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ExitButton{
public:
    void setup(void (*_setup)())
    {    
        _setup(); // we call the function pointer
    };
};    


void setup() // this is a void function
{
    cout << "calling void setup()" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    ExitButton eb;
    eb.setup(setup); // use a void function as a parameter
}
```

Comment: the setup function of the ofApp.cpp needs to be like that?

Comment: no, the problem is in  `void setup(void (*_setup));`, this takes a parameter which is a void pointer, and not a pointer to a void function

Comment: I tried that but now it throws me the following error: A reference to non-static member function must be called, did you mean to call it with no arguments? And if I add the (). Then it throws me the error I had before saying that void (*)() is not compatible with void

Comment: I'm not getting exactly what you want to do. The `update()` is a function that takes no parameters, but you are trying to call it with a void rvalue. Just post a minimal example without any headers, a plain main.cpp and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry that I was a typo. I mean to say exitButton->setup(setup()); in the update() of ofApp.cpp

Comment: Then just declare `void setup(void (*f)());` in `class ExitButton` and call it as `exitButton->setup(setup)`

Comment: So I tried your code in the main.cpp and it works but inside the class member the way I have it, doesn't work. I guess it is more complex that I thought.

Comment: Unfortunately in oF I can't access the main.cpp directly. Everything has to happen in ofApp.cpp. That's just how the framework works. But this make s a lot of sense. Thanks for taking the time