# How would I pass a function as a parameter in c++

Tags: c++, function, parameters, arduino, parameter-passing

```
class Stepper
{
public:
  Stepper(int en,int dir, int clk, void(*f))
  {

  }
};
class Turret : public Stepper
{
public:
  Turret(int x,int y, int z,void (*f)):Stepper(x,y,z,void(*f))
  {
  }
};
void TurretStep()
{

}
Turret t(2,3,4,TurretStep);
```

Alright so this gives me a void* is not a pointer-to-object type. All i'm trying to do is pass a void function as a parameter to my constructors.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860157/passing-a-void-function-as-an-argument-to-another-function

Comment: You can use `std::function`  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 problems.

The first is you don't have the correct **syntax for a function pointer**.

The syntax for a function pointer is

```
return_type(*name)(arguments)
```

Since your function has `void` return type and doesn't take any arguments, it's

```
void(*f)()
```

The second is in trying to **pass the function pointer `f` to the base class constructor**

Here you're passing the *type* to the base class, when in fact you just want to pass the variable

Incorrect (both in terms of the syntax and passing the type of the argument)

```
Stepper(x,y,z,void(*f))
```

Correct (just pass `f`, the function pointer variable itself

```
Stepper(x,y,z,f)
```

**Here is the code with the fixes:**

```
class Stepper
{
public:
  Stepper(int en,int dir, int clk, void(*f)())
  {

  }
};
class Turret : public Stepper
{
public:
  Turret(int x,int y, int z,void (*f)()):Stepper(x,y,z,f)
  {
  }
};
void TurretStep()
{

}
Turret t(2,3,4,TurretStep);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the empty parenthesis to the function pointer:

```
void(*f)()
        ^^
     no arguments
```

Also, `Stepper(x,y,z,void(*f))` is also wrong, because `f` is just a variable (like `x`, `y` and `z`), so why cast it to `void`?

```
Stepper(x, y, z, f); //'f' is just like a "normal" variable
```

Answer (score 1):

I use to do this way:

```
typedef void (TURRETSTEP)();

class Stepper
{
public:
    Stepper(int en,int dir, int clk, TURRETSTEP* f)
    {

    }
};


class Turret : public Stepper
{
public:
    Turret(int x,int y, int z, TURRETSTEP* f): Stepper(0, 0, 0, f)
    {
    }
};

void TurretStep()
{

}
```

I declare a typedef defining a "function template", is easy to do:

if your function is (for example):

```
char* ReadString(int a, short b, int etc);
```

simply surround function name with parenthesis, and make it uppercase like this:

```
char* (READSTRING)(int a, short b, int etc);
```

and add typedef declaration:

```
typedef char* (READSTRING)(int a, short b, int etc);
```

Comment: I'd suggest using C++ `using` syntax: `using TURRETSTEP = void(*)();`